# How to append a variable in SCP command in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scp

Below is my shell script in which I am trying to append $element in my below `scp` call in the if statement block.

```
for element in ${x[$key]}; do   # no quotes here
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "$element"
    if [ $key -eq 0 ]
    then
        scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_$element_5.data /data01/primary/.
    fi    
done
```

But whenever I am running my above shell script, I always get like this -

```
scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_.data No such file or directory
```

When I have taken a close look in the above error message, the above scp statement is not right as it should be -

```
scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_0_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

The value of `$element` should get replaced with `0` but somehow my above appending logic is not working. Is there anything wrong I am doing in the way I am appending $element in my above scp command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `t1_${element}_5.data`

`scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_${element}_5.data /data01/primary/.`

when you use `t1_$element_5.data`, bash will replace `$element_5` with its value,
you don't have `$element_5` defined, so you are getting

> t1_.data No such file or directory